# Passing variable to static function

Tags: php

I have some PHP that pulls all staff records in the DB.

I now want to add a clause, so it can `SELECT * WHERE companyId = x`.

Im using `GET` to retrieve the `companyId` to be used.

My question is, how can I pass $`companyClause` to the static function?

```
function viewStaffInCompany(){

    $results = array();
    $companyClause = $_GET["companyClause"];
    echo $companyClause . "<br><hr>";

    $data = Staff::getCompanyStaffList();
    $results['staff'] = $data['results'];
    $results['totalRows'] = $data['totalRows'];

    require( "templates/viewStaff.php" );

};
```

and

```
getCompanyStaffList();

public static function getCompanyStaffList( $numRows=1000000, $order="id ASC", $companyClause) {
    $conn = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );

    $sql = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM Staff WHERE $companyClause ORDER BY " . $order . " LIMIT :numRows";

    $st = $conn->prepare( $sql );
    $st->bindValue( ":numRows", $numRows, PDO::PARAM_INT );
    $st->execute();
    $list = array();

    while ( $row = $st->fetch() ) {
      $users = new Staff( $row );
      $list[] = $users;
    }

    // Now get the total number of staff that matched the criteria
    $sql = "SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS totalRows";
    $totalRows = $conn->query( $sql )->fetch();
    $conn = null;
    return ( array ( "results" => $list, "totalRows" => $totalRows[0] ) );
  }
```

Comment: var $variablename; in your function{}

Comment: You shouldn't. Atleast not the way it currently is as it would open the gate for sql injections (on some PDO configurations). Validate the content of the GET entry before you do anything else with it or modify the function to bind the parameter to the query in an appripiate way. After that look at the answer below.

Comment: thanks @Rangad will have a read up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as a parameter.

```
Staff::getCompanyStaffList(1000000, "id ASC", $companyClause);
```

But I would refactore this parameter list, because `$companyClause` is required, so, you will need to pass the first 2 params always, what has default values, if not given.

So it should be:

```
public static function getCompanyStaffList($companyClause, $numRows=1000000, $order="id ASC") {
```

Comment: This would create a security issue as it may lead to a possible sql injection.

Comment: thanks lolka, I've updated the code but its not working. Take on board what @Rangad said too will have a look at sanatising

Comment: its not returning any error messages, just a blank screen. Will have a look and update with a more useful response

Comment: use `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to see errors.

Comment: @lolka_bolka great thank you! I had the order wrong, didnt realise they both needed to be specified in the same